# Correct way of specifying a given date in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime

I am writing some T-SQL which needs to enforce a minimum date value onto some null fields:

```
DECLARE @epoch DATETIME;
set @epoch='1900-01-01';
select min = ISNULL(ValidFromDate,@epoch)
```

Is the string '1900-01-01' always going to return a datetime of Jan 1 1900 in any environment or will SQL server try to parse the string according to local culture rules?

If that's not good enough, what is the recommended way of specifying a particular date/time in T-SQL?

Comment: Quick counter-example `set language british;
DECLARE @epoch DATETIME;
set @epoch='1900-01-25';
select min = ISNULL(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@epoch)` gives an error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best format for string-based dates is the **ISO-8601** standard format.

For `DATETIME` variables and columns, this is either `YYYYMMDD` (for dates without time; without any dashes!) or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (date + time).

Contrary to popular belief, `YYYY-MM-DD` for `DATETIME` variables is **NOT** language-/dateformat-independent! If you try this, the second `CAST` will result in an error:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT CAST('2011-07-20' AS DATETIME)

SET LANGUAGE british
SELECT CAST('2011-07-20' AS DATETIME)
```

but this will work:

```
SET LANGUAGE british
SELECT CAST('20110720' AS DATETIME)
```

This is the best format since it's indepdendent of your language and dateformat settings in SQL Server.

For SQL Server 2008 and columns of type `DATE` (just date - no time), the format can also be `YYYY-MM-DD` (with the dashes) and that works for all settings, too.

Why there is such a difference between `DATE` and `DATETIME` is beyond me - that's just the way it is for now!

See Tibor Karaszi's excellent [The Ultimate Guide to the DateTime data types](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) for even more details and examples.

Comment: I suppose **us_english**, not **US_english** for case sensitive DBs