# SQL query not pulling correct year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
SELECT
    convert(varchar, dates, 101) 
FROM 
    database 
WHERE 
    dates BETWEEN '04/01/2015' AND '04/30/2015'
```

It returns all April dates but the problem is it is for every year (i.e. 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015). I think that it is not reading the last 2 digits of the year and just pulling everything from 2000 on. Am I correct in thinking this? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the dates field is a datetime data type?

Comment: This would happen if the `dates` column were defined as 'VARCHAR` or similar, not datetime. Might be helpful to see the table definition.

Comment: Store dates as dates, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates column is likely not defined to be a date type.  You can update the column type... or explicitly convert it in your query:

```
Select convert(varchar, dates, 101) 
FROM database 
Where convert(date,dates) BETWEEN '04/01/2015' and '04/30/2015'
```

The reason it would give you all April dates if your dates field was interpreted as a string of text is because all the April dates would be sorted together alphabetically.  If it were properly interpreting your field to be a date, it would be able properly filter them.

Comment: Yes alphabetically 04/01/2015 is before 04/02/2010 or even 04/02/1955

Comment: It adds around 10 seconds to the execution time but it works like a charm! Thanks @BrianPressler

Comment: You should probably convert the field to be a date type.  You can then index it and SQL Server will be able to use the index properly.

Comment: if i do Select convert(date,dates) then it speeds it up to 1 second processing :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide your dates in a standard format that SQL Server will understand correctly. See [Correct way of specifying a given date in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517804/correct-way-of-specifying-a-given-date-in-t-sql).

For you it will be:

```
Where dates BETWEEN '20150401' and '20150430'
```

Comment: That returned 0 rows

Comment: Is dates a date or datetime type field?

Answer (score 0):

In tSQL this would work for you:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, dates)
FROM [database]
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, dates) = 4 AND DATEPART(year, dates)=2015;
```